# Update record to set value from one of related records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

Let's say I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Companies 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50),
    Location nvarchar(100),
    BusinessType int
);

CREATE TABLE Employees 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CompanyId int NOT NULL,
    FirstName nvarchar(50),
    LastName nvarchar(50),
    SSN nvarchar(32),
    BusinessType int
);
```

How could I write a query that sets `Companies.BusinessType` to the `Employees.BusinessType` of one of the employees linked to that company?

It's safe to assume that all employees linked to one company will all have the same business type. So it doesn't matter which one of the related employees the value comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be storing this information only once, in the `companies` table.  But that is not what you are asking.

You ca update the table with an arbitrary matching business type using a correlated subquery:

```
update companies
    set businesstype = (select top (1) e.businesstype
                        from employees e
                        where e.companyid = companies.id
                       );
```

After setting the value, you should probably remove the column from `employees`.

Comment: I know the data should be stored just once. Based on new information from the client, I'm moving several columns from the many side to the one side. Thus, the purpose of this task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I add one question: If I wanted to update more than one column this way, would I need to include multiple `SELECT TOP (1)...` subqueries, or is there a way to combine them?

Comment: @JonathanWood . . . You can certainly repeat the subquery.  There are other approaches as well.  Whether they are worth the effort depends on how much data you have.  And if you have an index on `employees(companyid)`, the performance is probably fine with multiple subqueries.